# Aegir external API

Tags: drupal-7, aegir

I'm building a system that will utilize Aegir to manage a collection of Drupal sites, and I'd like to be able to trigger Aegir tasks (such as setting up new sites) remotely by other parts of the system.

For example, when a user sets up a new project, in a separate component of the system, it should send an authenticated message (ideally over http) to the hostmanager to automatically provision a corresponding site.

Is there a module that could provide this functionality or get me a head start on implementing it myself?

Answer (score 2):

I would try using drush alias files to run drush commands from the outside. Drush alias files allow you to authenticate remotely and run such commands. (some example on drush alias file - https://drupal.org/node/1401522).

Aegir (actually one of its components - provision) has integration with drush, so you can use commands like `provision-install` and other (see `drush help` for more).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Aegir Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/hosting_services):

> Aims to be a one-stop shop for all Web services functionality offered
>   within the Aegir Hosting System. It allows for remote site management
>   via the Services framework.